# Connect via Javascript SDK 6.1.1

Tags: directus

Apologies if i have misunderstood something, but as I understand the latest version of the SDK is 6.1.1 and the one mentioned in the documentation is 5.3.4.

The example in the documentation states

`const client = new DirectusSDK(...`

But this does not work when using the 6.1.1

`https://unpkg.com/browse/@directus/sdk-js@6.1.1/dist/umd/directus-sdk.js

How do I connect via version 6.1.1?